# Installation problems in virtualenv

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

Good day everyone, may i know how to install virtualenv in the pi? Thanks

```
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv

Cleaning up...

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 694, in get_page
    req, link, "connection error: %s" % exc, url,

TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're up-to-date.

general update

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

pip update

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

try to install virtualenv

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```